# ResultSet no guarda consulta

Tags: java, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cont = 0;
    try {
        String r = "001";
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "progra", "progra");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(COD_RESERVA) FROM RESERVAS WHERE COD_RESERVA='"
                + r + "'");
        try {
            while (rst.next()) {
                cont = rst.getInt(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
        if (cont >= 1) {
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(
                    "select precio_viaje from viajes where cod_viaje like (select cod_viaje from reservas where cod_reserva="
                            + r + ")");
            while(rset.next())
                System.out.println(rset.getInt(1));

            ResultSet rset1 = stmt.executeQuery(
                    "select precio_medio from medios_transporte where cod_medio like (select cod_medio from viajes where cod_viaje IN (select cod_viaje from reservas where cod_reserva='"
                            + r + "'))");
            while(rset.next())
                System.out.println(rset1.getInt(1));

            ResultSet rset2 = stmt.executeQuery(
                    "select precio from hotel where cod_hotel like (select cod_hotel from viajes where cod_viaje IN (select cod_viaje from reservas where cod_reserva='"
                            + r + "'))");
            while(rset2.next())
                System.out.println(rset.getInt(1));

        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La reserva no existe");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

En el código en java, al realizar la consulta no guarda nada en el ResultSet en cambio si cogo la misma consulta y la ejecuto directamente en el sqldeveloper si que me devuelve el dato buscado como se ve en la siguiente captura:

[image]

Ya he intentando otras formas de ejecutar la consulta sin éxito pero en ninguna he conseguido sacar datos de la consulta.

Al ejecutarlo me salta un error en la consola diciendo Juego de resultados agotado

Comment: Parece que en tu código falta encerrar entre ' ' el cod_reserva.

Comment: NO TE "COMAS" LAS EXCEPCIONES. Te dan información de los problemas de tu código. Como mínimo haz un *e.printStackTrace()* para ver el error.

Comment: Por si no quedó claro mi comentario: parece que a tu línea `ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select precio_viaje from viajes where cod_viaje like (select cod_viaje from reservas where cod_reserva="+ r + ")");` le falta `ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select precio_viaje from viajes where cod_viaje like (select cod_viaje from reservas where cod_reserva='"+ r + "')");` (las comillas simples rodeando tu variable r)

Comment: Si @AntonioVenerosoContreras, tu comentario quedó claro y esto debes publicarlo como respuesta para poder votarte.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que a tu línea

`ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select precio_viaje from viajes where cod_viaje like (select cod_viaje from reservas where cod_reserva="+ r + ")");`

le faltan las comillas simples:

`ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select precio_viaje from viajes where cod_viaje like (select cod_viaje from reservas where cod_reserva='"+ r + "')");`